# In HP-UX, how do you write a C program using PKCS#11 api?

Tags: kernel-modules, hp-ux, cryptography, hp

I am heavily confused by HP-UX's manual on its cryptographic module linked [here](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04609154&DocLang=en&docLocale=en_US).

It gives an example of a C code using PKCS#11 apis, but nowhere can I find information on where to find the shared object to use the PKCS#11 api. I have inferred that maybe the shared object is replaced by loading the module somehow, but if that's true, I don't understand how to load the module targeted at this c program.

Can somebody help me out on this?

Comment: Do you have this package installed? `HPUX-KCM_A.02.01.00_HP-UX_B.11.31_IA.depot `